# Edited my question, hasn't been reopened for a long time

Tags: support, status-completed

[Unable to create a bootable USB drive using Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349362/my-usb-wont-boot)

This was edited a week ago, and it still hasn't been reopened. Can someone look at it?

Answer (score 4):

It's reopened now. Posts that are edited after being closed are normally put in a queue to be reviewed by the community and potentially reopened, but the edit has to be within 5 days of the post closing (not really sure why, come to think of it). If it ever comes up again in the future, you can use the [`flag`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) link under a post to let us know.