# how do people assume that a question has been abandoned?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked this query [Was debian the first distribution to come and have the idea of changelog.gz and changelog.debian.gz?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388531/was-debian-the-first-distribution-to-come-and-have-the-idea-of-changelog-gz-and)?

I saw somebody comment at [Was debian the first distribution to come and have the idea of changelog.gz and changelog.debian.gz?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388531/was-debian-the-first-distribution-to-come-and-have-the-idea-of-changelog-gz-and?noredirect=1#comment692170_388531)

And I feel to understand the rationale behind that assumption if true. Could anybody shed more light on the subject.

It seems my question is related to also [Edited my question, hasn't been reopened for a long time](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/edited-my-question-hasnt-been-reopened-for-a-long-time) but there still seems to be ambiguity as how or on what basis closed votes are chosen.

There is no way for the asker/questionnaire to know why a question had closed votes :(

Comment: If you really want to delete this question, there should be a "delete" link towards the bottom of it, next to "share", "edit", and "close"

Comment: If you're curious about [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388531/was-debian-the-first-distribution-to-come-and-have-the-idea-of-changelog-gz-and?noredirect=1#comment692170_388531), let me know, and I can expound on it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm curious to know how you assumed or anybody else assumed that I had abandoned that question, and for the record, I do NOT want to delete it but really ask and get answer to my query/question given in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388531/was-debian-the-first-distribution-to-come-and-have-the-idea-of-changelog-gz-and

Comment: I was responding here to your question text "can somebody close this question please" -- if you intend to leave it open for someone (e.g. me) to respond, I'd suggest removing that text from this question.

Comment: I don't understand what you need here. If your question has been answered by the one you link to (not sure how, they're not duplicates), you can just delete it. Is there something else you are wondering about?

Comment: @JeffSchaller just edited the question a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: I assume you mean why a question had 1..4 close votes? Because once it is closed, a message appears with the reason.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I understand that, what I meant was shouldn't there be a way to let the asker/questionnaire know why it was closed. When I put up a close vote, there are a number of reasons for which I can put up a close vote, maybe the question is off-topic, maybe its a duplicate, in my question it isn't apparent why people closed it, that's what I'm trying to ascertain. For e.g. I saw quite a few people put up history questions including myself and people answered so wondering.

Comment: Your question has not (yet) been closed. Proposed duplicate-closures will insert a comment with a link to the target Q; for other types, people may or may not leave comments, but in the end, there's always stock text that's added to closed questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have enough reputation to cast close votes on your question, so you can also see what reasons others have given so far. Just click on the close button and look at the numbers:

> [image]
>   [image]

I haven't voted yet, and I don't intend to explain others' voting, so no point asking me anything else.

Comment: thank you, didn't know about that.